# Swagger UI running in Docker uses internal port; can't use try out function

Tags: docker, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-node-express

Using `swagger-node` I setup a project using `Express` and `swagger-ui-express`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:8-alpine

WORKDIR /opt/app

COPY package*.json ./
RUN yarn install
COPY . .

CMD [ "yarn", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: "3"

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 15000:10010
```

**Starting the container**

`docker-compose up`

The graphical API docs are reachable from the outside at `http://localhost:15000/api-docs`. However I can't use the "Try it out" function as Swagger takes the internal IP and port.

How can I change this so that the API can be tried from outside the container?

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution?  I have same issue.  It's calling the containers port running on Marathon instead of the external port.